# Why does whenever the player goes left or right it only plays my left animation?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I have .atlas folders playing my walking animation but then I went to add a walking animation for the left, and it does it when you go left and right and I don't understand why because I'm calling the two different texture arrays...

```
else if location.x > center {

    //moving to the right
    moveLeft = false;
    playerAnimate.run(SKAction.repeat(SKAction.animate(with: textureArray, timePerFrame: 0.15), count: 1))
    let move:SKAction = SKAction.moveBy(x: 18, y: 0, duration: 0)
    playerAnimate.run(move)
}
else {
    //moving to the left
    moveLeft = true;
    playerAnimate.run(SKAction.repeat(SKAction.animate(with: textureArray2, timePerFrame: 0.15), count: 1))
    let move:SKAction = SKAction.moveBy(x: -18, y: 0, duration: 0)
    playerAnimate.run(move)
}

var playerAnimate = SKSpriteNode()
var textureAtlas = SKTextureAtlas()
var textureAtlas2 = SKTextureAtlas()
var textureArray = [SKTexture]()
var textureArray2 = [SKTexture]()

override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    intializeGame();
    textureAtlas = SKTextureAtlas(named: "walkingAnimation")
    textureAtlas2 = SKTextureAtlas(named: "walkingAnimationLeft")

    for i in 1...textureAtlas.textureNames.count {
        let name = "win_\(i).png"
        textureArray.append(SKTexture(imageNamed: name))
    }

    for j in 1...textureAtlas2.textureNames.count {
        let name2 = "win_\(j).png"
        textureArray2.append(SKTexture(imageNamed: name2))    
    }
}
```

Comment: You should have got a warning saying it is not recommended to use the same texture name in 2 different atlases

Comment: Also. you never cancel your previous action, so both are running at the same time.

Comment: they aren't the same though.....one is walkingAnimation the other is walkingAnimationLeft. Also, how do I cancel my previous action then?

Comment: By removing actions or assigning keys

Comment: Also, the texture names are the same. You are using `win_1.png` in `walkingAnimation` and `win_1.png` in `walkingAnimationLeft`  This is bad. You also should not be using `.png` at all,  I would drop that.